# Callback when 'class' instance is created

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = (function(){

    var c = function(requests) {   
        bar();
    };

    c.prototype = {
        bar: bar
    };

    return c;

})();

var f = new foo();

f.baz(function(){
    console.log('new instance of foo created');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LecJM/

I would like to create a callback function which is called when a new instance of the "class" `foo` is created. Is this possible? Obviously the code above won't compile, I just want to give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Javascript is not - i repeat - is not object oriented. It just pretends to be so. You can fake it but it is not built into the language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/msT7A/)?

```
var foo = (function(){

    var c = function(requests) {
        // Initialize your instance
        // ...

        // Notify
        notifyCreated(this);
    };
    c.prototype = { ... };

    var createdCallbacks = [];
    c.onCreate = function(callback) {
        createdCallbacks.push(callback);
    }

    function notifyCreated(instance) {
        // Note: forEach requires ES5 or a shim
        // Just use whatever you want to loop over the array
        createdCallbacks.forEach(function(callback) {
           callback(instance); 
        });
    }

    return c;

})();

// Add callback *before* creating instances
foo.onCreate(function(instance){
    console.log('new instance of foo created', instance);
});
// Create an instance
var f = new foo();
```

Basically, you add a method to `foo` (and *not* to `foo.prototype`) to add a callback. Inside your constructor, you call all registered callbacks (here demonstrated with a separate internal function). To use, you *first* register a callback and then start creating instances.

**EDIT:** As requested, with just one callback:

```
var foo = (function(){

    var c = function(requests) {
        // Initialize your instance
        // ...

        // Notify
        notifyCreated(this);
    };
    c.prototype = { ... };

    // Use a dummy callback by default
    var notifyCreated = function(){};
    c.onCreate = function(callback) {
        notifyCreated = callback;
    }

    return c;

})();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/msT7A/1/)

**EDIT 2:** Heck, if you're only going to need one callback, you might as well get rid of the `onCreate` function and just expose the callback as a variable. There are a few downsides to this though:

- You can't do input checking, for example you can't test if the callback is actually a function before storing it.
- Others can trigger the callback externally through `foo.onCreate(anInstance)`.

If those are not problematic (for example if you're not exposing `foo` anyway), feel free to use this extremely simple snippet:

```
var foo = (function(){

    var c = function(requests) {
        // Initialize your instance
        // ...

        // Trigger callback
        c.onCreate(this);
    };
    c.prototype = { ... };

    // Expose callback on "class"
    c.onCreate = function(){};

    return c;

})();

// Set callback *before* creating instances
foo.onCreate = function(instance){
    console.log('new instance of foo created', instance);
};
// Create an instance
var f = new foo();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/msT7A/2/)

Comment: Thanks, looks good! But why do you need an array of callbacks?

Comment: @Johan You don't need to, it depends how you want to deal with multiple calls to `onCreate`. Do you want multiple functions to be able to be triggered? If yes, then you need to store all of them in an array so you can call them. later on. If not, you could do with just retaining one function (i.e. make `createdCallbacks` hold that function instead of an array). I just thought you wanted the first option because your suggested syntax looked very similar to binding an event handler (such as `$.click(callback)`).

Comment: One is enough in this case, the rest is exposed on a $.Deffered.promise. But since it lacks a "before"-callback, I wanted to add one myself. Would you mind showing me the code without using the array?

Comment: Thanks. From a performance point of view, woulnd't it be better to add `onCreate` to `c`'s prototype?

Comment: @Johan It wouldn't make sense to add it to the prototype. You want a function to be called whenever *any* instance is created, so it belongs more to `foo` than any particular instance of `foo`. Adding it to the prototype would also suggest that you can override it for one particular instance, but that wouldn't work since it may not be overridden on other instances.

Comment: @Johan As for performance, I doubt it will make much of a difference - I would guess it may be faster on `foo` since it doesn't go through a prototype chain, but you'd have to do some benchmarks to be sure. Either way, you should prefer code semantics over marginal performance gains: code that makes sense is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Thanks a lot for elaborating. How do I create the method as public for each instance, instead of static? Do I need to delcare it inside the constructor?

Comment: @Johan As I said, I don't see why you would do that. Yes, you *could* add it to the prototype (just add `c.prototype.onCreate = c.onCreate`), but what's the point? You'd need an instance of `foo` before being able to call the instance method, but the previously registered callback has already been triggered by the time you retrieve such an instance.

Answer (score 2):

```
var Foo = function (createdCallback) {   
   createdCallback();
   return this;
};

var bar = new Foo(function () {
   console.log("instance created");
});
```

Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Close, but I would prefer a separate method instead of a callback in the constructor, if possible?

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/LecJM/1/)

```
var foo = function() {
    this.baz();
};
foo.prototype.baz = function () {
    console.log('new instance of foo created');
};

var f = new foo();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't use the closure.